# Using a List<Dictionary<string,string>> with ServiceStack ORMLite SqlList

Tags: c#, servicestack, ormlite-servicestack

Has anyone else seen problems in trying to use a generic List of Dictionary< string,string > (or string,object) with the **SqlList** feature of ORMLite?

```
var data = Db.SqlList<Dictionary<string, string>>("exec my_storedproc p1,p2");
```

It throws the following exception:

```
Incorrect number of arguments supplied for call to method 
'System.String get_Item(System.String)'
```

I haven't debugged into the guts of it yet, but it appears to crash here when extracting the field defs:

```
public static T ConvertTo<T>(this IDataReader dataReader)
    {
        var fieldDefs = ModelDefinition<T>.Definition.AllFieldDefinitionsArray;
```

note: the underlying dialect provider is for sqlserver

**Update #1** 
digging deeper, the crash is triggered here, on the "String Item" property of the Dictionary:

```
namespace ServiceStack.OrmLite
public static class PropertyInvoker

    public static PropertyGetterDelegate GetPropertyGetterFn(this PropertyInfo propertyInfo)
    {
    ...
    var exprCallPropertyGetFn = Expression.Call(instanceParam, getMethodInfo);
```

**Update #2**
compiling the OrmLite with No_Expressions returns the propertygetter a little differently and lets it flow through, and the call to SqlList returns the correct number of items; however, each Dictionary has 0 items.  Seems it was able to create a new Dictionary for each record, but not able to insert the fields/columns.

Thoughts?

**Update #3** (hacked solution)

For those interested, I manually added a fix to do what I needed.  In OrmLiteReadExtensions, I added an "IsDictionary" to go with the IsScalar check, and then added a ConvertToDictionary.  Not the cleanest solution I'm sure, but works.  Here are the snippets:

```
public static bool IsDictionary<T>()
    {
        return typeof(IDictionary).IsAssignableFrom(typeof(T));
    }

internal static List<T> SqlList<T>(this IDbCommand dbCmd, string sql, object anonType = null)
    {
        if (anonType != null) dbCmd.SetParameters(anonType, true);
        dbCmd.CommandText = sql;

        using (var dbReader = dbCmd.ExecuteReader())
            return IsScalar<T>()
                    ? dbReader.GetFirstColumn<T>()
                    : IsDictionary<T>() 
                        ? dbReader.ConvertToDictionary<T>() 
                        : dbReader.ConvertToList<T>();
    }

public static List<T> ConvertToDictionary<T>(this IDataReader dataReader)
[...]
while (dataReader.Read())
     {
          var row = CreateInstance<T>();
          var roww = (row as Dictionary<string, object>);
          for (int f = 0; f < fields; f++)
          {
              roww.Add(dataReader.GetName(f), dataReader.GetValue(f));
          }
          to.Add(row);
     }
```

Comment: In v 4.0.17.0 I dont even see the *.SqlList<...>* method...

Comment: This is with 3.97.  I will have to look into how the SqlList works in 4.0.

Comment: This is definitely still an issue in 4.0.X.  There doesn't seem to be a simple way to query a generic SQL that returns a table (columns unknown) and have the results returned in a generic list.